# Correct syntax to add a mime-mapping to web.xml in a grails plugin

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin

I'm trying to add a mime-mapping element to the web.xml.

My current best stab is:

```
def doWithWebDescriptor = { xml ->
    xml + {
        'mime-mapping' {
            'extension'("htc")
            'mime-type'("text/x-component")
        }
    }
}
```

I know the code is being run as the above actually outputs an invalid web.xml. The following seems to be more logical but it doesn't actually have any effect:

```
def doWithWebDescriptor = { xml ->
    xml.'mime-mapping' + {
            'extension'("htc")
            'mime-type'("text/x-component")
        }
}
```

edit: I'm using grails 1.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
def doWithWebDescriptor = { xml ->
    xml << {
        'mime-mapping' {
            'extension'("htc")
            'mime-type'("text/x-component")
        }
    }
}
```

(note the `leftShift` instead of the `plus`).

Alternatively, if you want to ensure that your new element is inserted at a specific position within the XML, you can get the child element, after which you want your element to be inserted, and add yours with the `plus` operator. For example, I use the following code to add a new servlet-mapping:

```
def servletMappings = xml.'servlet-mapping'
servletMappings[servletMappings.size() - 1] + {
    'servlet-mapping' {
        'servlet-name'("myServlet")
        'url-pattern'("/myURL")
    }
}
```

If you want to dig further into this, have a look at `groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild` (the `xml` argument is of that type) and its superclass `groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can now accomplish the same thing by adding a `mime-mapping` element directly to the web.xml template in `src/templates/war/web.xml` like this:

```
<mime-mapping> 
    <extension>htc</extension>
    <mime-type>text/x-component</mime-type> 
</mime-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the only thing I could find referred to a config property that must be set in order to properly access mime-types in requests:

```
grails.mime.file.extensions = true
```

Try making sure this is set to true, and then try it again with the code that works?

Comment: not quite what I'm after I'm afraid, I tried this first, it doesn't seem to work for static files under web-app

Comment: Yup, sorry, but it was the only docs I could find that seemed somewhat relevant.  Good luck.